# How to replace multiple words with space in a string using Java

Tags: java, regex

I tried to replace a list of words from a give string with the following code.

```
String Sample = " he saw a cat  running of that pat's mat ";
String regex = "'s | he | of | to | a | and | in | that";
Sample = Sample.replaceAll(regex, " ");
```

The output is

```
[ saw cat  running that pat mat ] 
// minus the []
```

It still has the last word "that". Is there anyway to modify the regex to consider the last word also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
String Sample = " he saw a cat running of that pat's mat remove 's";
String resultString = Sample.replaceAll("\\b( ?'s|he|of|to|a|and|in|that)\\b", "");
System.out.print(resultString);
```

> saw  cat  running   pat mat remove

***DEMO***

http://ideone.com/Yitobz

Comment: Are you sure? OP's `..| that"` should have matched as well. (I do agree the missing space is probably an error.)

Comment: You need to use word boundary's `\bword\b`.

Comment: Thanks. this works. But It still fails if there is a space before 's. for example **pat's** work. But **pat 's** fails to remove _'s_

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have consecutive words that you are trying to replace.

For example, consider the substring

```
[ of that ]
```

while the `replaceAll` is running, the `[ of ]` matches

```
[ of that ]
 ^  ^
```

and that will be replaced with a  (space). The next character to match is `t`, not a space expected by

```
... | that | ...
```

What I think you can do to fix this is add word boundaries instead of spaces.

```
String regex = "'s\\b|\\bhe\\b|\\bof\\b|\\bto\\b|\\ba\\b|\\band\\b|\\bin\\b|\\bthat\\b";
```

or the shorter version as shown in [Tuga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326300/438154).

Comment: why not use the word boundary's in a group ? `\b(group)\b`

Comment: @Tuga I don't know. What does that gain us?

Comment: @Tuga Oh, I see what you mean. Yeah, that works wonders as well.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work, because you delete the " of " part first and then there is no space before the "that" word, because you deleted it (replaced)

you can change in two ways:

String regex = "'s | he | of| to | a | and | in | that";

or

String regex = "'s | he | of | to | a | and | in |that ";

or you just call Sample = Sample.replaceAll(regex, " "); again